# FileUpload.HasFile() always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

This is the code I use for my UpdatePanel.

The FileUploadAsync.HasFile() is always null.

I am wondering what is wrong with my asp.net page ...

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddFiles" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LkUpload" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LkUpload" runat="server" OnClick="LkUpload_Click" Visible="false">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUploadAsync" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried taking the fileupload outside the update panel? I've had that problem before.

I got this to work, try it out and let me know.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="futest.aspx.cs" Inherits="erpweb.futest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="smTest" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

codebehind:

```
    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            //do save process here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes and it doesn't change because actually it's a AsyncFileUpload so it shouldn't matter, it's an Ajax control.

Comment: I just added code from what I just tested and it worked. Give it a shot and let me know.